# How to calculate the k-th largest value in a sequence in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, dolphindb

I would like to know how to calculate the k-th largest value in a sequence. Is it required to sort the sequence and then retrieve the value by index? Are there any simpler and more efficient methods available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [searchK](https://www.dolphindb.com/help200/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/s/searchK.html#searchk), which is designed to find the k-th smallest element. To calculate the k-th largest element, you need to calculate the total length of the sequence and subtract k from it.

Note that the following statement cannot be used in SQL queries, because nested aggregate functions are not yet supported in distributed queries:

```
select searchK(val, count(val)-k) from t
```

This will result in an error message: `Can't use an aggregate function as the argument of another aggregate function`.

You can first calculate the total record count ”rows“ and then use *rows-k* as the parameter in `searchK`:

```
rows = sum(getTabletsMeta("/testDB/%", `pt, true).rowNum);
select searchK(volume, rows-k) from t
```